# Can't install pylint in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The problem is that when I try to add an extension for pylint in vscode I get a pretty long error message

```
C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python3.exe 
c:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.10.332292344\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip install -U pylint --user 

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python3.exe: 

can't open file 
'C:\Users\username\Documents\Programming\Python\beginning 

in vscode\Usersname.vscodeextensionsms-python.python-2020.10.332292344pythonFilespyvsc-run-isolated.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It looks like the final part of the error message involves a path that is lacking any slashes? Where do I go to fix that path so I can install the extension? Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say where the problem comes from, but it's probably some misconfiguration in VS Code.

#### Workaround

You can also install `pylint` manually. Use that `python.exe` which you use in your project. If you use virtual environment, use the `python.exe` inside it (in the `venv/Scripts` folder). However, seems that you are using your global python, which is also fine, but note that if you activate virtual environment in VS Code Terminal, you'll have to also install pylint for that virtual environment.

The command is

```
<path_to_python> -m pip install pylint
```

Now since you use your global python interpreter you can just

```
python -m pip install pylint
```

if you wish. It will install the pylint to the current environment, be it the global environment or a virtual environment. More precise would be the same python as VS Code tried:

```
C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python3.exe -m pip install pylint --user
```